# How to manage UITableView if number of sections are not confirmed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am using UITableView in which number of sections are created dynamically according to the data. From 1 to 12. Section names are the names of months. How can I check w.r.t to the sections name. My code is

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return [sectionArray count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [sectionArray objectAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

int count = 0;
for(int counter=0; counter<[sectionArray count]; counter++)
{
    NSString *month = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:counter];
    if([month isEqualToString:@"October"])
    {
        count = [octoberArray count];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"November"])
    {
        count = [novemberArray count];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"December"])
    {
        count = [decemberArray count];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"January"])
    {
        count = [januaryArray count];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"February"])
    {
        count = [febuaryArray count];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"March"])
    {
        count = [marchArray count];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"April"])
    {
        count = [aprilArray count];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"May"])
    {
        count = [mayArray count];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"June"])
    {
        count = [juneArray count];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"July"])
    {
        count = [julyArray count];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"August"])
    {
        count = [augustArray count];
    }
    else
    {
        count = [septemberArray count];
    }
}

return count;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

HistoryCell *cell = (HistoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"historyCell"];
if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"HistoryCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}

for(int counter=0; counter<[sectionArray count]; counter++)
{
    NSString *month = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:counter];
    if([month isEqualToString:@"October"])
    {
        cell.glassesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Glasses",[octoberGlassesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.unitLabel.text    = @"Unit";
        cell.dateLabel.text    = [octoberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"November"])
    {
        cell.glassesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Glasses",[novemberGlassesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.dateLabel.text    = [novemberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"December"])
    {
        cell.glassesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Glasses",[decemberGlassesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.dateLabel.text    = [decemberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"January"])
    {
        cell.glassesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Glasses",[januaryGlassesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.dateLabel.text    = [januaryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"February"])
    {
        cell.glassesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Glasses",[febuaryGlassesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.dateLabel.text    = [febuaryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"March"])
    {
        cell.glassesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Glasses",[marchGlassesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.dateLabel.text    = [marchArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"April"])
    {
        cell.glassesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Glasses",[aprilGlassesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.dateLabel.text    = [aprilArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"May"])
    {
        cell.glassesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Glasses",[mayGlassesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.dateLabel.text    = [mayArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"June"])
    {
        cell.glassesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Glasses",[juneGlassesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.dateLabel.text    = [juneArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"July"])
    {
        cell.glassesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Glasses",[julyGlassesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.dateLabel.text    = [julyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else if([month isEqualToString:@"August"])
    {
        cell.glassesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Glasses",[augustGlassesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.dateLabel.text    = [augustArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        cell.glassesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Glasses",[septemberGlassesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        cell.dateLabel.text    = [septemberArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}

return cell;
}
```

The application crashes. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What does the crash log say?

Comment: why do you loop through the section array in each cell?

Comment: May be I am doing wrong. Actually Name of the month is the name of the section and every section has its own array. Means If there are three sections named as(January,March,April) there will be three arrays for these sections. But its not confirmed that how many sections are there. I have sections array and data arrays for these sections, but don't know how to present them in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Anyway: you shouldn't have 12 different arrays for each months as variables. Please use NSArray *months, that will have from 0 to 11 your JanuaryArray, FebruaryArrary etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you don't clearly understand how `UITableViewDataSource` works. But if I understand your idea correctly the code below should fix the problem:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [sectionArray count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *yourMonthArray = //Here get an array for adequate month
    return [yourMonthArray count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *arr = @[@"January",@"February",...,@"December"];
    // asserts are optional. Just for sure you initialized your data well.
    NSAssert(arr.count == 12, @"The number of months is not valid");
    NSAssert(arr.count == [sectionArray count], @"Number of months is different than number of sections");
    return arr[section];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    HistoryCell *cell = (HistoryCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"historyCell"];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        // Please consider using UINib instread.
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"HistoryCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSString *month = [sectionArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.section];
    cell.glassesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Glasses",[octoberGlassesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]];
    cell.unitLabel.text    = @"Unit";
    NSArray *yourMonthArray = //Here get an array for adequate month
    cell.dateLabel.text    = yourMonthArray[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```